# Change Password not working in my symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement change password functionality in my symfony project via ajax and am getting 500 error,

Following is my code in template twig

```
<form id="changePasswordForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label class="all-label">Current Password</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter current password" id="currentPassword" name="currentpassword" aria-label="Password">
                    <img src="images/view.svg" class="view">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label class="all-label">New Password</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new password" id="newPassword" name="newpassword" aria-label="Password">
                    <img src="images/view.svg" class="view">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <label class="all-label">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter confirm password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmpassword" aria-label="Password">
                    <img src="images/view.svg" class="view">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="buttons float-end d-flex">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-5">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5 save-button">Save Password</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Following is my code in Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


    class ChangePasswordController extends AbstractController
    {
       
        public function changePassword(Request $request , UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
        {
           
            $currentPassword = $request->request->get('currentpassword');
            $newPassword = $request->request->get('newpassword');
            $confirmPassword = $request->request->get('confirmpassword');
    
    
            $user = $this->getUser();
    
            // Check if the current password is correct
            if (!$passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $currentPassword)) {
                return new JsonResponse(['success' => false]);
            }
    
            // Check if the new password and confirm password match
            if ($newPassword !== $confirmPassword) {
                return new JsonResponse(['success' => false]);
            }
    
            // Encode the new password
            $encodedPassword = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $newPassword);
    
            // Update the user's password
            $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);
            $entityManager= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
    
            return new JsonResponse(['success' => true]);
        }
    }
```

Following is my ajax code

```
$('.save-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = {
    currentpassword: $('#currentPassword').val(),
    newpassword: $('#newPassword').val(),
    confirmpassword: $('#confirmPassword').val()
  };


  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/change-password',
    data: formData,
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        alert('Password changed successfully!');
      } else {
        alert('Password change failed. Please try again.');
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    }
  });
});
```

Following is my code in routes.yaml file

```
change_password:
  path: /change-password
  controller: App\Controller\ChangePasswordController::changePassword
```

On my debugging i found that issue is generating if i pass `UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder`  as argument in `changePassword` function. It s generating 404 error in jax request

WHat is the isse , please help me to change password

Comment: Check logs on your request to know what is throwing an error, hard to guess without knowing why the request is throwing an error

Comment: What version of Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any more details i'd assume that your code is missing CSRF token in your Ajax request
in your template, add the CSRF token as a data attribute to your form:

```
<form id="changePasswordForm" data-csrf-token="{{ csrf_token('change_password') }}">
<!-- the rest of your code -->
```

Also you need to update the Ajax request :

```
$('.save-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var csrfToken = $('#changePasswordForm').data('csrf-token');
    
    var formData = {
        currentpassword: $('#currentPassword').val(),
        newpassword: $('#newPassword').val(),
        confirmpassword: $('#confirmPassword').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/change-password',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken // Include the CSRF token in the request headers
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // Handle success response
        },
        error: function() {
            // Handle error response
        }
    });
});
```

add route to the controller :

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/change-password", name="change_password")
 */
public function changePassword(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    // Rest of your code
}
```